# Filter Kubernetes events by deployment name or label selector

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl

When running `kubectl get events`, is there a way to filter by events without knowing the name of the pod?

I am trying to do this with [Azure Pipeline's **Kubectl** task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/kubernetes?view=azure-devops), which is limited to passing arguments to `kubectl get events`, but does not allow subshells and pipes, so `grep` and `awk` are not available.

I tried using `kubectl get events --field-selector involvedObject.name=my-microservice-name`, which works to an extent (i.e., for the deployment resource), but not for the pods.

Using `kubectl get events --field-selector app.kubernetes.io/name=my-microservice-name` returns no results, despite having that label configured as seen in `kubectl describe pod <my-microservice-name>-pod-name`.

Ideally if there is a way to use wildcards, such as `kubectl get events --field-selector involvedObject.name=*my-microservice-name*`, would be the best case scenario.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have azure environment, but I can show events on pods

```
master $ kubectl get events --field-selector involvedObject.kind=Pod
LAST SEEN   TYPE     REASON      OBJECT      MESSAGE
<unknown>   Normal   Scheduled   pod/nginx   Successfully assigned default/nginx to node01
5m13s       Normal   Pulling     pod/nginx   Pulling image "nginx"
5m8s        Normal   Pulled      pod/nginx   Successfully pulled image "nginx"
5m8s        Normal   Created     pod/nginx   Created container nginx
5m8s        Normal   Started     pod/nginx   Started container nginx
```

If you need target on particular pod, you should work with `involvedObject.kind` and `involvedObject.name` together.

```
master $ kubectl run redis --image=redis --generator=run-pod/v1
master $ kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --generator=run-pod/v1
master $ kubectl get events --field-selector involvedObject.kind=Pod,involvedObject.name=nginx
LAST SEEN   TYPE     REASON      OBJECT      MESSAGE
<unknown>   Normal   Scheduled   pod/nginx   Successfully assigned default/nginx to node01
16m         Normal   Pulling     pod/nginx   Pulling image "nginx"
16m         Normal   Pulled      pod/nginx   Successfully pulled image "nginx"
16m         Normal   Created     pod/nginx   Created container nginx
16m         Normal   Started     pod/nginx   Started container nginx
```

Why I knew `involvedObject.kind` works, because its json output shows the key is exist

```
        "involvedObject": {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "fieldPath": "spec.containers{nginx}",
            "kind": "Pod",
            "name": "nginx",
            "namespace": "default",
            "resourceVersion": "604",
            "uid": "7ebaaf99-aa9c-402b-9517-1628d99c1763"
        },
```

The other way you need try is `jsonpath`, get the output as json format

```
kubectl get events -o json
```

then copy & paste the json to https://jsonpath.com/ and play around with [jsonpath practices](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/)

Comment: Thanks @BMW.  Would this also work if the pod names have the random characters at the end like this?

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                 READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
my-microservice-name-4098151155-494nl   1/1       Running   0          1m
```

This is where i am having the most trouble due to the extra characters and the inability to specify them in the Azure task.  I may have to switch to PowerShell or Bash instead.

Comment: it should work. the `field-selector` is looking for the key of `involvedObject.name`, it never minds the random characters, if you worry about it, you can add quota or double quota on it

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me:

`$ kubectl get events`
`Events:`
`  Type    Reason     Age   From                          Message`
`  ----    ------     ----  ----                          -------`
`11m         Normal    Killing             pod/temp-centos-db2-connectivity-test-5b6fcb7d98-rn5mn    Stopping container centos`
`$ kubectl get events --field-selector involvedObject.kind=Pod,involvedObject.name=temp-centos-db2-connectivity-test`
`No resources found in default namespace.`
`$`

Comment: seems your pods don't running in `default` namespace, then you can add one more filter `involvedObject.namespace=xxxx`

Comment: They actually were running the `default` namespace.  I am able to get results back if I use the full name as part of the field selector: `--field-selector involvedObject.name=temp-centos-db2-connectivity-test-5b6fcb7d98-rn5mn`.  We also have the `app.kubernetes.io/name/temp-centos-db2-connectivity-test` label, but without any noticeable difference.

Comment: that’s great, seems your problem is fixed. If you need fuzzy search, think about jsonpath, i already mentioned in answer

Comment: Oh, I meant that I can get results if I used the full name (with the random characters at the end), but not if I just used the `temp-centos-db2-connectivity-test` string.  It will be difficult for me to get the full pod name with the Azure Pipelines Kubectl task, so would that "fuzzy search" help in that regard?  I am just trying to get the same results as `kubectl describe pod`, but without knowing the full pod name.